# Problemas para instalar pdftotext en python3

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda, línea-de-comandos

Comunidad, estoy intentando instalar pdftotext pero me pide tener microsoft visual studio c++ 14.0 para poder hacerlo, pero no logro instalarlo de cualquier forma.
Estoy ocupando scrapping con pdf, por eso necesito ese comando. Pido disculpas si no uso el lenguaje correcto, no soy programador, estudio economía y estoy intentando innovar en ésta área.
Gracias.

Comment: [Aquí](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) te lo puedes descargar

Comment: Lo instalé y me sigue arrojando errores para instalar el modulo pdftotext